# How to create a virtual keyboard in userspace?

Tags: linux, keyboard, drivers, daemon

I'm trying to generate keypress/release events similar to those produced by typing on a physical keyboard, but from a process that isn't attached to any actual hardware.

Comment: You'd probably have to pass the events to evdev in some way.